# Nested Knockout.js templates, poor performance

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am using knockout templates to represent tabular data while maintaining freedom to manipulate and style the 'rows' and 'columns' in a natural way.

I have a foreach binding over my rows, each row holds a variable with the name of the row template it should use.

I use another foreach binding to loop through cells in each row, every one of those has a variable containing its template name.

This results in highly customizable tables that I can use across my app and reduces code duplication - I'd love to keep doing it.

---

I run into an issue with performance when representing tables with more than a handful of rows (15 rows x 5 columns takes ~1000ms to render).

I don't think it's a problem with the creation of the table, I've tried to do that in the recommended ways like adding to the base array and calling `valueHasMutated`.

Any re-render triggers the lag.  The causes of re-rendering are tough to predict, I've had it happen on visibility toggling, even simple updates to an unrelated observable string.

Is there anything I can do to make these templates more performant?  I have set breakpoints inside some of the knockout scripts that handle templates and can see it updating the dom between the drawing of every cell and row.

Comment: Have you tried applying deferred updates? http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/deferred-updates.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Components can be used in a way that is very similar to templates.  Components typically take a `ViewModel` parameter, but can be used without one if supplied with a `params` property in the binding.

Components are loaded asynchronously and seem to render once instead of `n = row x col` times.  This has reduced rendering time from 7s to just under 1s for my largest tables, I believe my bottleneck is elswhere now.

**Example template:**

```
<div class="grid-body" data-bind="foreach: Rows">
  <!-- ko template: { name: 'DefaultCellTemplate', data: Cells } -->
  <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

**Converted to component**

```
<div class="grid-body" data-bind="foreach: Rows">
  <!-- ko component: { name: 'DefaultCellTemplate', params: Cells } -->
  <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

Instead of using special script tags to define a template, components must be added using `ko.components.register()` before they can be used.

**Example template markup**

```
<script id="DefaultCellTemplate" type="text/html">
  <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
</script>
```

**Converted to ko.components.register**

```
ko.components.register('DefaultCellTemplate', {
  template: '<span data-bind="text: $data"></span>'
});
```